# How can I restore everything except stored procedures, functions, users from SQL Server 2019 native backup into another DB Server.?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2019

How can I restore everything except stored procedures, functions, users from  SQL Server 2019  native backup into another DB Server?

We are planning to setup a QA environment from clone of PROD SQL Server 2019.
The QA environment will have a few custom changes to the "Programmability(SPs, functions etc.)" section which we want to retain.

In order to  refresh the latest data from PROD, the custom changes will be wiped off after the next  backup/restore.

How can I restore everything except stored procedures and functions from  SQL Server 2019  native backup into another DB Server?
Is it possible in SQL Server 2019?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I restore everything except stored procedures and functions from SQL Server 2019 native backup into another DB Server? Is it possible in SQL Server 2019?

No, not directly. Backups need to be consistent and restored fully.

Indirectly, you can script these objects to a secondary copy of the database, temporarily, and manually restore them after the backup restore finishes. I do similar post-restore scripts in a SQL Agent Job so that I can repeatedly run the restore process I need in my QA environment.